# Calculated field using MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to calculate a person's age using MariaDB, the table is already created and I'm trying to alter the table to add the calculated column, this is my syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE user_details 
ADD Age AS TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dateOfBirth, CURDATE());
```

I've got no idea why I get a syntax error.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB requires that the data type of the generated column (in your case presumably an `INT`) is specified, and that the expression be enclosed in parentheses. You need to use:

```sql
ALTER TABLE user_details 
ADD Age INT AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dateOfBirth, CURDATE()))
```

Unlike MySQL, MariaDB (as of 10.2.1) supports non-deterministic built-in functions (in your case `CURDATE`) in generated columns, *as long as the column is `VIRTUAL` (the default) and not indexed*. See the [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/#expression-support).

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=78c5aac07605f953af4b6f5724f69622)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 issues in your query:

1. The expression of generated column must be enclosed with parenthesis.
2. The column datatype must be specified - even when it is generated column.
3. The expression of generated column cannot use non-deterministic function CURDATE().

The latter problem cannot be fixed.

> I'm trying to calculate a person's age using MariaDB

Do this in a query when you need in the age value really. Or create according view.

Comment: #3 is not true for MariaDB if the column is `VIRTUAL` and not indexed. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the method below. Then add an INSERT trigger for new rows.

```
ALTER TABLE user_details
ADD Age INT;

SET @@sql_safe_updates = 0;

UPDATE user_details
  SET Age = TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dateOfBirth, CURDATE());

SET @@sql_safe_updates = 1;
```